Processing 500k records crashes the server. How to batch it?
I have a database table holding 500k records. I need to load these records, do an API call, fetch data from this API endpoint, and save new data back to the database.
I tried to do it like this (simplified code):
task get_new_data: :environment do
  data = Model.where('column IS NOT NULL).order('id DESC')
  data.each do |d|
    puts '...info print...'
    api_call = API::Call(...)
    d.assign_attributes(attr1: api_call.data1,
                        attr2: api_call.data2,
                        ...)
    d.save!(validate: false)
    put 'another info print...'
    sleep(0.5)
  end
end

So what happened when I ran this code was that maybe for the first 3-4 minutes, I didn't see anything in the terminal window when I ran this rake command on the server. After that, I started seeing the puts statements. In another few minutes (maybe 5), the terminal window froze. I could see in the database table that the records were updated - so I thought that it's only the terminal window that "got broken".
After another 15-20 minutes, the server's CPU and RAM memory went up to 100% usage and I was not able to ssh to the server (that was expected due to the CPU/RAM 100% usage). Similarly, the Rails app was unreachable - blue error screen (expected as well).
At this point, I was just waiting when the server will fully crash. After another 30mins or so, the CPU/RAM memory got released, the Rails app was again reachable - the rake task finished. But, it didn't finish completely, it processed "only" about 350k records, so I had to run the rake task again to finish the remaining 150k records. Now, this second run was completed successfully.
The thing is that I'll need to run a similar task and iterate over the 500k records at least 6 more times, and I don't want to go through the similar experience as described above.
What is the right way to process such datasets without killing the server? Should I somehow batch the records by, say, 10k chunks? Or is there a better way to handle this thing differently? I currently don't use Sidekiq in the project.

Can the API calls be batched by using Typheos? The limit here is really going to be HTTP IO and not your database.

I don't know Typeos, I have to look how it works. Regarding the API call, I am limited by the provider to do no more than 2 API calls within 1 second, so I am putting a sleep in the end of the loop (I didn't include it in the original post)

At that rate you would need to run the task for almost three days uninterupteed which is going to be problematic. I would maybe add a column to flag the rows that have been updated and then have the task update a few thousand rows and have a runner restart it peroidically.

@Stefan at 500m records running at the optimum speed of two requests per second it would take a little under 8 years to complete the task. Oh my.

"What is the right way to process such datasets without killing the server?" – instead of processing the models inline, I would create a background job for each model that needs to get updated and have a worker process them asynchronous (within the API limits). This also allows to easily retry jobs that failed because of network issues.

Apologies and thanks for catching it. It's indeed 500k, not M!

Rails supports batching records, and it's easy to implement.
Instead of
 data.each do |d|

Use
 data.find_each do |d|

The batch size is limited to 1,000 records by default but you can override this with a :batch_size argument.
Official documentation is here...
https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Batches.html

That's going to be a pretty big improvement for memory usage but running the HTTP call is going to bottleneck it so badly that it's going to take days to complete.

sleep(0.5) also looks not good. If some request fail, all the task fail, need to catch exception

Using find_in_batch and find_each will solve your RAM and CPU problems. However, I see a problem with too many API calls. Is there an API that retrieves information in batches, or can you create it on the data source side?

Unfortunately, I cannot. I can either use this API service for free (with the limitation of requests per 1 second), or I can use some other paid alternative. Due to the nature of the project, though, I am not allowed to incur new costs.
